# getting same reference for two different instance of a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have two instances of a lightning component, one on a record detail page and another in utility bar. I'm getting same component reference for both component. I have implemented WebSocket for chat message, on onmessage event of WebSocket I'm getting a problem. On onemessage event I trying to update DOM of components but getting same component reference for both instance's WebSocket event, and both updates are going to newly rendered component (in utility bar).

I captured reference of both component in doInit method (stored component reference in `window.chatComponents` list variable) and check `window.chatComponents[0] === window.chatComponents[1]` it is giving `true`.

I want to update both components. Please help.[image: screenshot of both components]

Comment: Seeing some code would probably help us diagnose the issue. Would you mind sharing?

Comment: Problem solved. 
Actually I was storing Component in helper as `this.cmp = component`   and helper (this) in `window.chatComponents` list. 
Problem was that all instances of a component share a common helper, so `helper.cmp` variable was being overwritten by newly created component.
List  `window.chatComponents` contains multiple items (all reference of same helper).